# Loading red-arrow into serverless lambda

Tags: serverless, apache-arrow

I have a [serverless](https://serverless.com) ruby lambda.

I want to use [red-arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/main/ruby/red-arrow) to process some data but when I add `require 'arrow'` to my lambda it throws an exception:

```
require: cannot load such file -- arrow (LoadError)
```

Any idea how I can make this work?

Note: I haven't even tried to deploy this, this error occurs when I run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my serverless configuration was not picking up the gems specified in the Gemfile - I had to do a `gem install red-arrow` and that fixed it.